# Convert string to JSON or get the value of keys

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have a string like this:

```
a = '{test: "3", company: "hi", time: "1397758516000", test: "29", test: "48"}'
```

I want to get the value of all the keys. I wanted to parse it like:

```
JSON.parse(a) //which throws the error --> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

a['device'] //Get the device value
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Is this Javascript code intended to be run in a browser?

Comment: that isn't valid JSON, so the solution is to correct your JSON string.

Comment: Firstly, that is not valid JSON code. Secondly, you need to do `var arr = JSON.parse(a)` and it will need to be `arr.device` not `arr['device']`

Comment: Yes, This code is supposed to run in the server. It's from a open source project. I don't actually control the string but I can. Time for some `java`. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Dutchie432: `arr.device` and `arr['device']` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use eval function to get the JavaScript object, but the problem with JSON.parse is that your string is not valid. The keys also should be wrapped in the quotes like this:

```
a = '{"device": "3", "company": "hi", "time": "1397758516000", "lat": "29.339533333333332", "lon": "48.009258333333335"}';
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Volter9 said, you have incorrect JSON string. If you want to keep it, try with:

```
var output = JSON.parse(a.replace(/([a-z]+):/gi, '"$1":'));
console.log(output.device);
```

Comment: The regexp replace will mess up if any of the values in the bad JSON contain a letter followed by colon.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix your JSON, as shown in Volter9's answer, your code for getting the value also need to be fixed. It should be:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(a);
var device = parsed.device; // or parsed['device']
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON is not json, it is a native js object.

```
{"device":"3","company":"hi","time":"1397758516000","lat":"29.339533333333332","lon":"48.009258333333335"}
```

is valid one.

```
a = {test: "3", company: "hi", time: "1397758516000", test: "29", test: "48"};
```

You can do `JSON.stringify(a)` to convert the native js object to valid json.

Comment: His native JS object is enclosed in quotes, so it's a string, and `JSON.stringify` will turn it into the JSON for a string, not the object he wants.